# Apply GoDaddy signed SSL certificate to sub-domain

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I have a site that is hosted on a dedicated GoDaddy server. Currently I have a GoDaddy signed SSL certificate which has been applied to the domain mysite.com.

In order to increase the speed of my site I have created the subdomain static.mysite.com in order to serve up the cookieless files such as images and style sheets.

The issue I now have is that there is a self-signed SSL certificate now applied to the sub-domain which causes an error in the browser when the site is viewed.

So, is there a way to apply the GoDaddy signed SSL certificate to my static sub-domain as well as the main domain? If so how would this be done through cPanel or WHM?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Self-signed certificate is not good because website using [self signed certificate gives browser warning](https://www.clickssl.net/blog/why-am-i-facing-the-certificate-not-trusted-error) that decrease site's trustworthiness in the eye of customers. It is good for testing purpose that is to be accessed by you only. But still you want to apply self signed certificate on cPanel Server then read more at [this resource](https://www.webhostinghero.com/generate-install-self-signed-ssl-certificate-cpanel-server/).